# How to add a hidden field inside webgrid column in MVC action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I want to create hidden field in Webgrid **PollId** column which i am exactly not sure how to add some extra fields in this scenario

```
    public ActionResult Index(string mode)
    {
         List<WebGridColumn> columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
         columns.Add(new WebGridColumn() { ColumnName="PollId", Header="Id", Format= (item) =>  });
         ViewBag.Columns = columns;
         ViewBag.Columns = columns; 
         return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add hidden field using `string.Format` in your controller action

```
columns.Add(new WebGridColumn() { Header = "", Format = (item) => {
    return new HtmlString(  string.Format("<input type="+"hidden"+" value="+"Poll"+" id="+"Mode"+" />   ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

and use a strongly typed helper in your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ColumnName, new { id = "ColumnName" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing to support legacy browsers. You could use jQuery to apply a hidden style to the header and the rows of the first column or to simply hide them directly.

```
$(function () {
    $('table th:first-child, table td:first-child').hide();
});
```